# Passing CStringArray to Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a dialog box which returns the result of multiple selections from a list box in the form of a CStringArray I pass the returned result to a thread for processing of the files. I reference the array in the thread like so:

```
CStringArray* m_CStringArray = (CStringArray*)pParam;
```

I access the elements as:

```
m_CStringArray->GetAt(1);
```

But I get an empty element. If I get the count using.

```
INT_PTR total_count = m_CStringArray->GetCount();
```

It does return a proper count to the array passed in. What is the proper way of accessing a CStringArray element passed to a thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting undefined behaviour.  A mistake you might have made is to use a local `CStringArray` when you started the new thread, but forgot that the local copy is likely to go out of scope before the new thread gets processor time.

The easiest way around this is to allocate the `CStringArray` on the heap (using `new`) and let the thread dispose of it.

```
if(m_ProcessDlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
{
    CStringArray *arr = new CStringArray;
    arr->Copy( m_ProcessDlg.m_ProcessArray );
    CWinThread *pThread = AfxBeginThread( ExtractThread, (LPPARAM)arr );
}
```

Comment: I think you may be right the array might be going out of scope since it is a thread and running background processes. How would I go about allocating it on the heap given the passed pParam?

Comment: You have to do that *before* starting the thread.  *ie* The user data that you send through the `_beginthreadex` call (or whatever you're using) should be a pointer that was allocated with `new`, rather than a pointer to an object on the stack.

Comment: But when the dialog is closed the pointer will be destroyed should I just copy the pointer to an array stored in the mainframe and just access it from there. Would that be more efficient than trying to pass it in the thread?

Comment: Perhaps you should show the existing code that invokes the thread and passes the array to it, and I will then show you what I am talking about.

Comment: if(m_ProcessDlg.DoModal() == IDOK){

    CWinThread *pThread = AfxBeginThread (ExtractThread, &m_ProcessDlg.m_ProcessArray);